# How to construct a ternary expression in C# using Convert.ToInt32?

Tags: c#

I want to create a simple ternary expression similar to the following:

```
    Convert.ToInt32(stringname.Substring(0,2)) != 99 ?
    Convert.ToInt32(stringname.Substring(0,2)) : 15
```

I get an error about incompatibilities between int and bool. Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: What is the content of stringname?

Comment: Can you write a [mcve]? I cannot reproduce this as the code compiles on my end. At least it does in LINQPad and dotNetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/mtM6re

Comment: I see no problem with this:
`void Main()
{
    string stringname = "88888";
    int x =  Convert.ToInt32(stringname.Substring(0, 2)) != 99 ?
        Convert.ToInt32(stringname.Substring(0, 2)) : 15;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}` so you should embed you problem a bit more.

Comment: Please also be exact in which error message you get. Only way I can see to get an error involving a bool and an int and some incompatibility message is to try to do `bool x = <your expression>` which gives "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

Comment: ... or `int result = 99 ? Convert.ToInt32(stringname.Substring(0, 2)) : 15;`

Comment: Your example is incomplete. You must assign your ternary expression to something to make is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Does it *have* to be a single line? Apparently you already know the logic. Why do you need to cram it into a single code line? Cramming too much code into a single line will only make reading and debugging unessesarily hard.

Debugging will be hard, because you never know wich of those 4(four!) function calls is throwing the exception. It is also unessesarily slow, as you are doing the same two operations twice in a row. Just do it once and store the result.

My advise is to split up the code using temporary variables. One command + 1 assingment per line. This will make debugging and reading doable. Do not worry about performance. Between Compiler Optimisations and the JiT compiler, there is decent chance any underused variables will be cut out at runtime in a release build.